# Discord.js V14 Bot Ping CMD

Tags: discord.js

I am new to coding I was just making a simple ping command when I went to run it I got this error I have tried fixing it but I can't seem to find the problem please help me! I have been following this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IgOXmQMT68&list=PLv0io0WjFNn9LDsv1W4fOWygNFzY342Jm&index=1).

ping.js:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Return my ping!'),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const messsage = await interaction.deferReply({
            fetchReply: true
        });

        const newMessage = `API Latency: ${client.ws.ping}\nClient Ping: ${message.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp}`
        await interaction.editReply({
            content: newMessage
        });
    }
}
```

handleEvents.js:

```
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = (client) => {
  client.handleEvents = async () => {
    const eventFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/events`);
    for (const folder of eventFolders) {
      const eventFiles = fs
        .readdirSync(`./src/events/${folder}`)
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
      switch (folder) {
        case "client":
          for (const file of eventFiles) {
            const event = require(`../../events/${folder}/${file}`);
            if (event.once)
              client.once(event.name, (...args) =>
                event.execute(...args, client)
              );
            else
              client.on(event.name, (...args) =>
                event.execute(...args, client)
              );
          }
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  };
};
```

interactionCreate.js:

```
module.exports = {
  name: "interactionCreate",
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
      const { commands } = client;
      const { commandName } = interaction;
      const command = commands.get(commandName);
      if (!command) return;
      try {
        await command.execute(interaction, client);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({
          content: `Something went wrong while executing this command...`,
          ephemeral: true,
        });
      }
    }
  },
};
```

Error:

```
TypeError: command.execute is not a function
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\mikay\OneDrive\Desktop\v14 Bot\src\events\client\interactionCreate.js:11:23)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mikay\OneDrive\Desktop\v14 Bot\src\functions\handlers\handleEvents.js:20:23)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\mikay\OneDrive\Desktop\v14 Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:81:12)
    at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\mikay\OneDrive\Desktop\v14 Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\mikay\OneDrive\Desktop\v14 Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\mikay\OneDrive\Desktop\v14 Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:480:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\mikay\OneDrive\Desktop\v14 Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:320:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\mikay\OneDrive\Desktop\v14 Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
```

Comment: `console.log(command)` to see what `command` gives, then edit it in the post

Comment: What is in your `handleEvents.js` file? It's probably an issue with what you're passing into the arguments of `execute()` in `interactionCreate.js`

Comment: @zmehall I just added the handleEvents.js file code

Answer (score 0):

Remove await on 11

```
commands.set(command.data.name, commands);
```

remove s from the last command